# Which gender for words "Magnificum Consilium"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, medieval-latin

I would like to name a product in Latin because I find it original and attractive language. I was looking for a translation for the words "great advice" so I found "Magnificus Consilium" which was supposed to mean either "Grand Idea" or "great advice".  but then I figured it can't be right since the gender should be the same between the noun and adjective.

So I came up with "Magnificum Consilium". I wonder if this is the correct version if I would like the product to symbolize something like "Grand Idea" or "great advice"? Also I found that the adjective can be written before or after the noun. Is this really the case and if so, is it still preferable to write after the noun.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, *magnificum consilium* is correct. You are right to note that adjectives must agree with the noun they modify in gender, and so *magnificus* would be incorrect, because it would be masculine, and *consilium* is neuter. The gender of a noun is generally fixed, and the adjective, which can change gender, follows.

*Magnificum consilium* does indeed mean “great advice” or “great plan.”

Yes, adjectives can be written before or after the noun. No, it is not preferable to put it second. According to Wikipedia's [well-sourced entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_word_order#Adjective_position) on the subject of Latin word order, “adjectives which express a subjective evaluation [⋯] usually go before the noun.” This applies here, but if you want to put *magnificum* second, by all means do so—Latin word order is not arbitrary, but it is free.